# Input mask on email field a good idea?

Tags: input, email, guidelines

A colleague of mine is arguing that we should use an input mask for email fields.

Personally I don't think it is necessary. For phone numbers I can understand since a phone number can be written in different ways.

However everybody knows how to write an email address. Is it really useful to use a mask (and all the trouble it can get you with multiple devices)? Will people forget the @ if we don't provide the mask? I don't think so.

If the user enters an invalid email address we already use inline error (on blur) so what is the point. What do you guys think?

Comment: Practice has shown that the combination of delimiter placeholders and input fields is quite convenient: [react-flexinput-mask](https://orudnev.github.io/react-flexinputmask-demo/)

Comment: @Oleg Hmmm I doubt it. I tried your demo and erasing the email is quite cumbersome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By itself, it doesn't make sense for a new user to be shown an input mask for an email. Their email may be from any domain and extension, so an `@` mask is actually a deterrent since most people expect to type it and probably *will* type it. So now you need to expect an `@` symbol and move the cursor to the next field seamlessly.

For a returning user, it is helpful to provide autocomplete suggestions from a history of logins on the specific device/browser (which is a "complete" suggestion and not an input mask.)

Ideally, the only place for input masks for email is when you are registering a new domain-specific email (common with company/corporate email IDs), where you type in your `<username>@<company name>.<tld>` and everything after `@` remains either constant for everyone, or is limited to a small number of domains.

Answer (score 1):

Email address is a common input field these days. We see it on login forms, register forms, ... .

I think placeholder for email address field is good and clear enough even for below average users these days!